# Querying a variable from a MATLAB struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have an array of structs in MATLAB, all of which have the same structure (same fields).
I'd like a quick way to compile an array that contains all values of specific field from across the struct array. Is there any way doing this without using loops?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your array is named `a` and you have a field `b`. Accessing `a.b` gives you a list of the values of `b` fields for each element in `a`. If you want to turn that into a list, just wrap the list in `[]`. That is:

```
>> a = [struct('a', 1, 'b', 10, 'c', 100), struct('a', 2, 'b', 20, 'c', 200)];
>> a
a = 
1x2 struct array with fields:
    a
    b
    c
>> a.b
ans =
    10
ans =
    20
>> [a.b]
ans =
    10    20
>> [a.c]
ans =
   100   200
```

If you have a matrix of structs, you can use the above method to get a vector then reshape it into a matrix using:

```
>> reshape([a.b], size(a))
ans =
    10   111
    20   222
```

Comment: turn into a "vector/matrix" probably?